# React-fontawesome - icon says class is 'fa fa-undefined fa-2x'

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to use the window-close icon in my react app. https://fontawesome.com/icons/window-close?style=regular

It's not showing up and the class list says: `fa fa-undefined fa-2x` so something must not be working right.

My component is pretty small so it's not a lot of code.
Details component:

```
import React from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import { faWindowClose } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

const Details = (props) => {
    const className =
        'col details-col' + (props.showDetails ? '' : ' d-none');

    return (
        <div className={className}>
            <FontAwesome icon={faWindowClose} size={'2x'} />
            <h3 className={'text-center title details-title'}>
                Order Details
            </h3>
            <h4>{props.activeOrder.title}</h4>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Details;
```

Here is the full rendered HTML:

`<span icon="[object Object]" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-undefined fa-2x"></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I was importing the wrong fontawesome library.  I removed `import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';` from my imports.  I added `import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';` to my imports after installing it and it worked beautifully!

As requested by brooksrelyt, I followed the excellent tutorial here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-font-awesome-5-with-react

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this?

Comment: I added the tutorial link now.